# Having Google Services (gcm) in a separate module in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to move `gcm` codes to another module rather than my app's main module, to make my code cleaner and also to provide other modules of my app to have access to `gcm`.

It seems that I should have `google-services.json` placed in the root of the module and that module should have **the same** `package name` which `gcm` is set to work with. Obviously I can't do that, because the main module has that `package name` and another module **can't have the same** `package name`.

Is there any solution to place `gcm` in another module?

Comment: I did but using the old GCM API. No json file required, everything was in the manifest..

Comment: I donot understand the question.

Comment: @k3b The question is this: "Is there any solution to place gcm in another module?" and I've explained the reason I can't do this by just dragging the gcm code to another module.

Comment: I'd love to know if there is a solution to this.